# List filter not searching all fields

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a list and have it populated with data, but when I enter something in the filter box it will only filter based on the actual ID of the item or who it was modified.  It won't filter based on the extra rows.  I added the two rows that I want specifically to filter by as indices and told it to regenerate, but it's still not working (did that 8 hours ago).

Comment: are the fields present in your view?

Comment: @PirateEric Yes.  There's one view, all the fields in the item are in it.